# Enter key submits the form

Tags: javascript

When I press enter key it submits the form...
I want to prevent submitting form but `e.preventDefault` function is not working either.

```
enterKeyFunction.addEventListener('keyup',  async function (e) {
    
   e.preventDefault()
 
    let namee = document.getElementById("search___product").value
    console.log(namee)
    if(namee == "")
    {
      alert("Please enter the product name...!!")
    }
    else {
//do something else 
}
```

Comment: You're only preventing default on keyup, not enter, change your event listener to "submit"

Comment: Okay. I am not calling submit function it gets called automatically after clicking enter button on input field.

Comment: put an onclick attribute on your HTML form that runs a function that prevents default and submits only if whatever key you want pressed is being hit. Note that disabling the enter key for submitting a form is bad practice.